# Tizen wearable - conect the emulator to posible devices

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I'm very new to Tizen and also to the Tizen ide. I want to test my "Hello World" App with the Emulator (vis 2.3.1). I created a VM and opened it, but I can't play my App on it. The screen is black, but I see a watch, like the Samsung Gear S2.
I tested already to add the Emulator-VM to the List of connected Devices, but it doesn't accept the showed destination IP-Adress of the Emulator-Watch with the error: "failed to connect to remote target'IP-Adress' ".

I've already searched in the forum for answer, but they wasn't helpful.
How can I run my application on the VM in the Emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the tizen 2.4 mobile version and 2.3.1 wearable version on windows7.

But, I test sample plroject named Widget. There is no problem on launcing.

If you share your APK, someone would be test launcing.

Thanks

Hello widget sample app launching

[image]